# PHP PDO Segmentation fault error on null return value

Tags: sql-server-2005, pdo, segmentation-fault, php-5.3

Currently I am using freetds to connect to a MSSql server where I am pulling in a lot of accounting data. The data is pulling in fine until it hits a null value. At that point I am not receiving any PHP errors. Instead I am getting the following error in the apache error log.

> [notice] child pid 10235 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

I did some searching for this and found [this page](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45849), but it does not really help. The query I am using looks something like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.PEREND), t2.ERATE, t2.EEXTEND, t2.EARNDED, t1.ENTRYSEQ
       FROM UPCHKD as t1 LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT EARNDED, PEREND, ERATE, EEXTEND, ENTRYSEQ FROM UPCHKD
                    WHERE (EARNDED LIKE '401K%'AND EARNDED NOT LIKE '401KL%') AND
                          EMPLOYEE = ? AND PEREND >= ? AND PEREND <= ?) as t2 ON t1.PEREND = t2.PEREND
       WHERE t1.PEREND >= ? AND t1.PEREND <= ? AND t1.EMPLOYEE = ? ORDER BY PEREND
```

And I am getting the data using a while loop like the following,

```
while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //Deal with data here
}
```

I can not tell if this is a problem with PDO, my database layer, MSSQL, or my query. Also, I would like to point out that if I take the query and run it manually using MSSQL studio, it runs fine, and shows the null values properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this issue works by adding if null statements to all return columns like so,

```
ISNULL(t2.ERATE, 0) as ERATE, ISNULL(t2.EEXTEND, 0) as EEXTEND, ISNULL(t2.EARNDED, '') as EARNDED
```

If nulls are found now, they are returned as zeros without error. It is not the prettiest, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation faults are no fun to deal with. The best answer I can give you is to continually place `die('okay');` calls in various places to see how far in different coding blocks you get before you hit a seg fault. (You won't see anything if there was a seg fault).

It's also worth just trying to just upgrade everything to the latest versions: PHP, PDO, etc.